# In Inorder traversal of BST, how could pointer go back to the parent node?

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am sorry this question could be ignorant，but I am so confused.

```
public static void InOrderRecur(TreeNode<char> treeNode)
{
    if (treeNode == null)
    {
        return;
    }  
    InOrderRecur(treeNode.LChild);
    Console.Write(treeNode.Data); 
    InOrderRecur(treeNode.RChild);
}
```

1. After some recursive steps, the pointer went to the leftmost node.
2. Check the leftmost.leftChild, which is null.
3. Print the leftmost node.
4. Check the leftmost.rightChild, which is null.
5. Then we need to go back to the parent node. But I don't know which line of code could accomplish this function?

[For example, which code could make pointer go back to 18 from 12?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfcxG.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just step through the code with a debugger. There is no moving pointer. The function gets a reference (pointer) which it never changes. It passes another one (LChild or RChild) to the recursive call.